# Python Webscraping: grequests vs. mult-threaded requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

I'm trying to make web-scraper I'm writing in Python faster.

Currently I fire up a set amount of scraper threads, create a queue with a list of URLs I want to scrape and let them dequeue entries so they can scrape.

grequests states it's asynchronous but I'm not sure what the quite means beyond firing multiple threads (like I'm doing) and using gevent to trigger an event when it's finished.

Does grequests do anything more beyond create a thread per job and will it technically run more *quickly* than the program I've outlined above?

Comment: A web scaper usually spents the far most time waiting for I/O. You can't speed that up, just run multiple request at once. So, using a diffetent task scheduler is not going to have a large effect on it. It might make a difference in other scenarios where layency is a problem.

Comment: @KlausD. How would grequests improve performance with latency? Prioritize attending to requests that are done earlier? To add more context to my program: Each thread is also assigned a proxy and generally 70% of them have a high response time (10-30 seconds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out:

https://adl1995.github.io/a-comparison-of-response-times-using-urllib-grequests-and-asyncio.html

TL;DR:

"Using `aiohttp` with `asyncio` seems to be the best option. Its response time is almost 50% less than `grequests`."